# Telerik RadGrid - hide left-most column

Tags: wpf, telerik, hide, radgrid

Can't remember / driving me crazy - how to hide the upper-left-most cell/column of a Telerik WPF RadGrid (so all column headers are flush-left?)  I know it's something ridiculously easy/ simply forgot.

Answer (score 11):

You can set RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

On **RadGridView** go to **Open Property Builder** Click on **MasterTemplate** on Left side and Uncheck the **ShowRowHeaderColumn** in settings tab.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbFla.png)